SQL Delight no such table error when inserting documents Kotlin Multiplatform
I am getting this error :
co.touchlab.sqliter.interop.SQLiteExceptionErrorCode: error while compiling: INSERT INTO FavCoinData (
  id,
  symbol,
  name,
  image,
  current_price,
  fully_diluted_valuation,
  total_volume,
  high_24h,
  low_24h,
  price_change_24h,
  price_change_percentage_24h,
  total_supply,
  max_supply,
  last_updated
) VALUES (
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?
)
no such table: FavCoinData

Every time I want to add something to my database. I have another database that works fine. Reloading the project doesn't help.
my swift code:
 for i in self.FavCoinData {
                        LocalDatabase().saveFavCoinsData(
                            id: i.id, name: i.name, symbol: i.symbol, image: i.image, currentPrice: i.current_price, fullyDilutedValuation: i.fully_diluted_valuation, total_volume: i.fully_diluted_valuation, high_24h: i.high_24h, low_24h: i.low_24h as? KotlinDouble, price_change_24h: i.price_change_24h as? KotlinDouble, price_change_percentage_24h: i.price_change_percentage_24h as? KotlinDouble, total_supply: i.total_supply as? KotlinDouble, max_supply: i.max_supply, last_updated: i.last_updated
                        )
                    }

my iosMain db class file:
package com.example.kotlinmultiplatformapp
import app.cash.sqldelight.db.SqlDriver
import app.cash.sqldelight.driver.native.NativeSqliteDriver
import com.crypto.database.Database
import com.crypto.database.FavCoin
import com.crypto.database.FavCoinQueries
import com.crypto.database.FavCoinData
import com.crypto.database.FavCoinDataQueries



actual class DriverFactory {
    actual fun createDriver(): SqlDriver {
        return NativeSqliteDriver(Database.Schema, "test.db")
    }
}

class LocalDatabase {
    private val driverFactory = DriverFactory()
    private val database = createDatabase(driverFactory)
    private val favCoinQueries: FavCoinQueries = database.favCoinQueries
    private val favCoinDataQueries: FavCoinDataQueries = database.favCoinDataQueries
    fun getFavCoinsData(): List<FavCoinData>{
        return favCoinDataQueries.selectAll().executeAsList()
    }
    fun saveFavCoinsData(id: String, name: String, symbol: String, image: String, currentPrice: Double,
                         fullyDilutedValuation: Double?,
                         total_volume: Double?,
                         high_24h: Double?,
                         low_24h: Double?,
                         price_change_24h: Double?,
                         price_change_percentage_24h: Double?,
                         total_supply: Double?,
                         max_supply: Double?,
                         last_updated: String){
        favCoinDataQueries.insert(id, name, symbol, image, currentPrice, fullyDilutedValuation, total_volume, high_24h, low_24h, price_change_24h, price_change_percentage_24h, total_supply, max_supply, last_updated)
    }
}

my .sq file:
(placed inside sqldelight.com.crypto.database folder)
CREATE TABLE FavCoinData (
  id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  symbol TEXT NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  image TEXT,
  current_price REAL NOT NULL,
  fully_diluted_valuation REAL,
  total_volume REAL,
  high_24h REAL,
  low_24h REAL,
  price_change_24h REAL,
  price_change_percentage_24h REAL,
  total_supply REAL,
  max_supply REAL,
  last_updated TEXT NOT NULL
);
selectAll:
SELECT *
FROM FavCoinData;
deleteById:
DELETE FROM FavCoinData WHERE id = ?;
insert:
INSERT INTO FavCoinData (
  id,
  symbol,
  name,
  image,
  current_price,
  fully_diluted_valuation,
  total_volume,
  high_24h,
  low_24h,
  price_change_24h,
  price_change_percentage_24h,
  total_supply,
  max_supply,
  last_updated
) VALUES (
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?
);

I tried reloading projects multiple times.
Different database tables work just fine.
code structure
